# IIS, EC2, Web Farm, Web Deploy and ELB

Tags: asp.net, iis, amazon-ec2, load-balancing

I'm a developer now developing my startup. I really don't know much about IIS setup. I will host my startup on Amazon EC2. And I want to know how can I scale my application if my traffic increase. I been reading about MS Deploy and Web Farm Framework here: https://serverfault.com/questions/127409/iis-configuration-synchronization-for-web-server-farm . And I want a simple architecture, with not to much configuration. So I been looking an experience with an IIS web farm and Amazon ELBs. And I did not find any one.

So the question is:

- It is possible to make a IIS web farm with Amazon ELBs?
- Any experience on Ec2? IIS web deploy or WFF and/or without ELBs?
- What you recommend for an easy web farm setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do almost anything you want with IIS on EC2.  They are full servers (well window 2k8 datacenter edition) and you can open any ports you need to communicate between servers.  [Here](http://mebbinet.blogspot.com/2011/05/aws-ec2-with-web-farm-framework.html)  is an explicit tutorial on how to set up WFF, for example, on EC2.

The question is, are you sure you need to build a web farm?  If you simply want to have multiple servers running your code then you can accomplish this without anything more than IIS and the tools that EC2 provides.

You build your app so it uses shared resources (like a session state server, central location for storing user uploaded content), configure a server the way you like it, and capture a server image ([AMI](http://aws.amazon.com/amis)).  You use this image when you configure [AutoScaling](http://aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/) to launch new instances based on server metrics (like CPU usage), and they would be automatically added to the load balancer when launched.

The last challenge is ensuring servers launched automatically are running your latest code.  You can write a custom program to get the latest code from somewhere (like SVN) on server startup, or you can use something much simpler like Dropbox to handle the synchronization.